# Angulairjs Update page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a app with node-webkit and angulair.
In the page I have a loop. A object can be on or off. when it is on the text should be red.
when you click on a icon its going on or off but when I try to change the color from js it wont work. The page doesnt update itself. What can i do?

This is the page:

```
<div ng-repeat="sensor in sensors">
    <div class="moticaIcon" ng-click="SetLight(sensor.id)">
        <img ng-src="{{sensor.pictrue}}" width='100%'> 
        <p style="{{states[sensor.id] == true ? 'color:red' : ''}}">{{sensor.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="moticaIconSpace"></div>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.SetLight = function(name) {
    $scope.states[name] = !$scope.states[name];
    if ($scope.states[name]) {
        nativeConnection.SetSensor(name,"on");
    } else {
        nativeConnection.SetSensor(name,"off");
    }
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to take a look at Angular's `ngStyle`.

Looking at your code, you can do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="sensor in sensors">
<div class="moticaIcon" ng-click="SetLight(sensor.id); myStyle={color:'red'};">
<img ng-src="{{sensor.pictrue}}" width='100%'> 
<p ng-style="myStyle">{{sensor.name}}</p>
</div>
<div class="moticaIconSpace"></div>
</div>
```

Now, when you click the icon, it will change the color of the paragraph to red.

Here's the documentation link for another example:
[AngularJS: API: ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: Thanks! ngStyle is very usefull. thanks to you I could improve all my code.